# Is it possible to pass a stage variables to a custom authorizer in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm currently developing an API using AWS API Gateway. I'm issuing a JSON Web Token (JWT) to my client. That JWT is signed using a secret. I'm currently storing the secret in stage variables.

I want to use a custom authorizer to validate the JWT's signature. However I can't seem to find a way of passing the stage variable containing my secret to my custom authorizer.

For the authorisation endpoint issuing the JWT, I've used *Lambda Proxy Integration* to pass the secret from the stage variable to my Lambda function. However there doesn't seem to be an equivalent feature for custom authorizers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not currently possible to access stage variables from your custom authorizer function. However, we are considering this for future development.

I would urge against storing secrets in stage variables and opt for a  secret management solution (such as [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/)) instead. KMS can be easily called from within your custom authorizer function.

Comment: thanks for this answer!
what about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164747/custom-authorizer-context-variable-in-api-gateway-http-integration-url

Comment: do you have any example on how we can acheive that using KMS?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit later :) but from [current documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html) it seems now it's possible to use stage variables.

> **Identity sources**
>
> You can optionally specify identity sources for a Lambda authorizer.
> Identity sources specify the location of data that's required to
> authorize a request. For example, you can specify header or query
> string values as identity sources. If you specify identity sources,
> clients must include them in the request. If the client's request
> doesn't include the identity sources, API Gateway doesn't invoke your
> Lambda authorizer, and the client receives a 401 error.
>
> The following identity sources are supported:
>
> - Header value   $request.header.name
> - Query string value $request.querystring.name
> - Context variable   $context.variableName
> - Stage variable $stageVariables.variableName