# Custom authorizer context variable in API Gateway HTTP integration URL

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I would like to use an API Gateway HTTP integration towards an endpoint, where certain parts of the URL are provided by the custom authorizer (e.g., user ID or user grants).

I could definitely use a Lambda integration but that introduces quite significant response time overhead.

Unfortunately syntax that works for stageVariables does not seem to work for custom authorizer context - `${context.authorizer.variableName}`.

*Note: To answer some comments, yes, the warning sign is there bacause I used a dummy `url` string. Has nothing to do with the fact that replacement of authorizer context variables does not work for me, no matter what the URL is.*

[image]

Comment: What does the ⚠️ say if you hover over it? What if you disregard it and try anyway?  There are cases (the details of which I naturally don't recall at the moment) where the console warns of something being unknown, yet it works at runtime.  Not sure whether this might be one of those.

Comment: Or, potentially, omit the `$`.

Comment: Clarified the warning sign with an extra note in my question.

Comment: hello, did you manage to use context variables in the HTTP integration endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to valid, meaning like https://example.com/foo with a protocol and hostname.

Starting with `url/` is never going to be valid.

Comment: Yes, it does have to be valid and it produces a warning sign in my screenshot. However, I only shortened the url so that the variable text fits in the input box. Replacement does not work with valid URLs (that do not produce a warning sign).